# How to pivot data in Hive with aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, impala

I have a table data like below and I want  to pivot the data with aggregation .

```
ColumnA    ColumnB            ColumnC
1          complete            Yes
1          complete            Yes
2          In progress         No
2          In progress         No 
3          Not yet started     initiate 
3          Not yet started     initiate
```

Want to Pivot   like below

```
ColumnA          Complete    In progress     Not yet started
1                 2               0                0
2                 0               2                0
3                 0               0                2
```

Is there anyway that we can achieve this in hive or Impala?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` with `sum` aggregation:

```
select ColumnA,    
       sum(case when ColumnB='complete'        then 1 else 0 end) as Complete,
       sum(case when ColumnB='In progress'     then 1 else 0 end) as In_progress,
       sum(case when ColumnB='Not yet started' then 1 else 0 end) as Not_yet_started
  from table
 group by ColumnA
 order by ColumnA --remove if order is not necessary
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this in spark scala.

```
     val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
        val test = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(  ("1", "Complete", "yes"),
                                        ("1", "Complete", "yes"),
                                        ("2", "Inprogress", "no"),
                                        ("2", "Inprogress", "no"),
                                       ("3", "Not yet started", "initiate"),
                                        ("3", "Not yet started", "initiate"))


                                        ).toDF("ColumnA","ColumnB","ColumnC")
      test.show()
       val test_pivot = test.groupBy("ColumnA")
                           .pivot("ColumnB")
                           .agg(count("columnC"))

  test_pivot.na.fill(0)show(false)


       }
```

and the output

```
|ColumnA|Complete|Inprogress|Not yet started|
+-------+--------+----------+---------------+
|3      |0       |0         |2              |
|1      |2       |0         |0              |
|2      |0       |2         |0              |
+-------+--------+----------+---------------+
```