# Group by a column in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to write a hive query to solve the below problem. Can I get some pointers on solving the problem?

I have a sale table with 3 columns (ID, codes, amount). I want to group by ID column, and have the codes and amount related to an ID, in a single row.

Sample Input

```
ID  codes   amount

100  20      30
100  10      15
100  11      12
200  30      40
200  40      50
```

Expected Output

```
Id  code1 code2 code3 amount1 amount2 amount3

100  20    10    11     30      15      12
200  30    40           40      50
```

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52191974/2700344

Answer (score 0):

you need to do  you can get more [detail](https://support.treasuredata.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001451248-Hive-Presto-Standard-SQL-Tips)